# How to get metrics of multiple windows drives using Cloudwatch agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I currently have this code in my cloudwatch agent config file, but in the Cloudwatch dashboard, I am only seeing the metrics for C:. Is it possible to collect multiple drives uncombined?

```
"metrics_collected": {
            "LogicalDisk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "Free Megabytes"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "C:",
                    "D:"
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: How many disks do you have?

Comment: I have 2. It might be an issue somewhere else because this did work on a different instance.

Comment: Try using `"*"` then

Comment: That works as usual, but I was trying to separate the metrics.